# How to implement IDatabaseInitializer with SQL Server CE 4.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce-4

I'm new to EF Code First.

I created a subclass of `DbContext` and added some `DbSets`.

I made subclass of `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>` and implemented the following in the context, here is what my context looks like:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
  public Context() : base("Database") {  }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.CreateConnection("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
    Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
  }

  public DbSet<NameEntity> Names { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Case> Cases { get; set; }
}
```

After I run the following and check the apps files I don't see a generated database:

```
public App() //App ctor
{
  using (Models.Context context = new Models.Context())
  {

  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `.sdf` file for SQL Server CE 4.0 only shows up once you've actually **stored** something in it....

Comment: Database gets created and initialized when you make operation with context, access DbSet or make  some insert/updates. Did you try any of these?

Comment: I did in the DatabaseInitializer.Seed but it's never called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must force EF somehow to create database. It can be done by:

- Using context (either storing something or reading something) - `Seed` operation doesn't count in this case because `Seed` is executed after database is initialized but you need something to trigger initialization
- Manually force initialization

Example:

```
context.Database.Initialize(false);
```